# Why is "`" required around table in OrmLite / SqlLite / Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

Using OrmLite with android I have tried experimenting with a simple query:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> results = queryRaw("SELECT * FROM transaction");
```

Unfortunately I recieve an exception:

```
near "transaction": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM transaction
```

I found this confusing, and after stepping through and seeing what the Orm generates through compiled statements I realised the syntax should be:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> results = queryRaw("SELECT * FROM `transaction`");
```

I am just slightly confused as to why this is required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Transaction" is an SQLite3 keyword.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Relevant quotes from that page, up at the very very top:

> The SQL standard specifies [...] keywords which may not be used as the names of tables [...]
> [...]
> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it.

Documentation is your friend.<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* Except when it isn't. But in this case, it is.</sup>